# Javascript null value sent erroneously to method

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, null

Javascript code:

```
var x = null;
var action_data = {x:x};
$.get(
  '~/MyController/MyAction',
  action_data,
  function(result){
    //do_something
  }
);
```

Controller action:

```
public class MyController: Controller{
  ...
  public ActionResult MyAction(string x)
  {
    //here, x is the string 'null';

  }
}
```

Can someone explain to me why the string "null" is sent to the action instead of the value null? Thanks

Comment: because u set var x = null; it is passed as string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because u passed data null which converted to string and set to your action:

```
var x = null;
x="any thing"; // you need to change x value to be sent here
var action_data = {x:x};
$.get(
  '~/MyController/MyAction',
  action_data,
  function(result){
    //do_something
  }
);
```

if you want to pass null:

```
var x;
var action_data = {x:x};
$.get(
   '~/MyController/MyAction',
   action_data,
   function(result){
     //do_something
   }
 );
```

Comment: I actually want the value to be null in some cases. So in my method, i want `(x == null)` to be `true`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so thanks to Ahmed, i came up with the solution:

```
var x; //without the null initialization
```

does the trick ;)